# Inspect ExecutorService details

Tags: java, executorservice

Is there a way to dig into an `ExecutorServer` object to see how many threads are currently being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (executor instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
    int poolSize = ((ThreadPoolExecutor) executor).getPoolSize();
    // or
    int currentlyActive = ((ThreadPoolExecutor) executor).getActiveCount();
}
```

But generally, you should know that, because you have constructed the service (unless it is hidden in some bad API)

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  The executor was generated using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tpool)` and I was generally unaware that it could be cast to ThreadPoolExecutor.  Good to know!